# Showing syntax error with Error Code: 1064 near WITH 'cohort_items AS ( SELECT DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', U.created_at)::date as cohort FROM

Tags: mysql, sql

Response:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'cohort_items as (   select     month(U.created_at) as cohort' at line 1

This is my code which is showing error:

```
-- - users (id, created_at)
WITH cohort_items AS (
SELECT month(U.created_at) AS cohort_month,
       id AS user_id
FROM public.users U ORDER BY 1,2)
```

I have tried to find the syntax error but I have not been successful. Kindly help me find out where am I doing wrong.

Comment: The error message indicates that you're using MySQL, why did you include the SQL-Server tag?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? CTE is not available until MySQL 8.0.

Comment: There's also no `date_trunc()` function in MySQL. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541326/postgresqls-date-trunc-in-mysql

Comment: @deadman - it's clearly a [tag:mysql] error message. No idea why you thought adding the [tag:sql-server] tag back was a good idea.

Comment: @Barmar It's MySQL 8.0 only

Comment: There's still no `date_trunc()` function. I'm not sure why it's saying the error is at `cohort_items`, but try fixing the rest of the syntax and see if that resolves it.

Answer (score 0):

**Date_trunc** is not an mysql function ,
you can use date or DATE_FORMAT()

you can use this-

```
SELECT date(U.created_at) AS cohort_month,
               id AS user_id
       FROM public.users U
       ORDER BY 1,2
```

OR

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(U.created_at,'%d-%b-%Y') AS cohort_month,
                   id AS user_id
           FROM public.users U
           ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is showing that issue is with 'WITH' statement. It is still showing an error.

Comment: @ShailendraDhakad, add a semicolon before the `with`, or after the immediately preceding statement.

Comment: He got a MySQL error message, so he's not using SQL-Server.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `DATEADD` and whilst it has a `DATEDIFF` function, it's definition is not the same as the SQL Server one of the same name.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - yes you are right i have removed the mysql code

Answer (score 0):

MySQL -- prior to V8 -- doesn't support `WITH`.  Nor does it support `date_trunc()`.  You can get the first day of the month using:

```
SELECT (DATE(u.created_at) - INTERVAL (1 - DAY(u.created_at)) DAY) as cohort_month
```

I'm not sure if the `WITH` is supports, so your query might have other errors.  If so, then ask *another* question, because this question is specifically about the `DATE_TRUNC()`.